# Enviando e-mail através do Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Sou iniciante aprendendo Node.js e estou travado numa questão de envio de e-mail no site como se fosse aquele ''fale conosco'' utilizando Node.js

A questão é, eu consigo enviar o e-mail, porém ele só envia quando a página dá erro e não atualiza. Apresenta a mensagem na tela "Cannot POST /index''

Mas se eu arrumo esse problema pra direcionar pra própria página (no caso, index), ele não envia o e-mail, não consigo entender, poderiam me ajudar?

A forma que vou colocar no exemplo ele envia o e-mail, porém retorna uma página com o erro informado ("Cannot POST /index"), porém se eu corrijo isso colocando no server.js:

```
app.use('/index', require('./routes/index'));
```

O e-mail não é enviado. E se eu tiro o ''action'' ou deixo ''action = /'' no HTMl, ele retorna a página certa, porém não envia o e-mail também.

Obs: estou usando express

```js
server.js

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var enviar = function(req, res, next) {
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'fulano@gmail.com',
        pass: '123'
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'fulano@gmail.com',
    to: 'ciclano@live.com',
    subject: 'Nome: ' + req.body.nome + ' / Telefone: ' + req.body.telefone,
    text: req.body.mensagem
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
next();
};
app.use(enviar);
```

```html
index.html

<form method="POST" action="/index">
    <div class="image fit">
        <h3>Nos envie uma mensagem!</h3>
        <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
    Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" />
    <br>
    Telefone: <input type="text" name="telefone" />
    <br>
    <footer>
        <button class="button special" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa mensagem de erro "Cannot POST /index" é porque a rota index não deve estar aceitando acesso pelo método POST

Aqui tem um exemplo de rota que recebe um post de formulário:

```html
let express = require("express"),
  path = require('path'),
  nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let app = express();

app.use(express.static('src'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
  let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
          user: 'hello@gmail.com',
          pass: 'test'
      }
  });
  let mailOptions = {
      // should be replaced with real recipient's account
      to: 'info@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Assunto do email',
      body: req.body.mensagem
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
  });
  //Redirecionar
  res.writeHead(301, { Location: 'index.html' });
  res.end();
});

let server = app.listen(8081, function(){
    let port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

Os campos do seu formulário você pode pegar com o req.body. Você pode alterar este exemplo com as suas configurações de conexão.

No caso, o formulário ficaria da seguinte forma:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/send-email">
    <div class="image fit">
        <h3>Nos envie uma mensagem!</h3>
        <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoar">
    </footer>
</form>
```